# Cannot Connect Links on Postman with Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, postman

I have 3 almost identical code simulating 3 crypto-miners, each run on a different port 5000, 5001 and 5002. The only difference is literally the last line of code:

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

I then connected them on postman with each other. However, the 5001 failed to connect to the other two every time. The other two works perfectly. [image]

The error msg looks like the following: 
[image]

This does not make sense to me since the python scripts and postman settings are symmetric and this 5001 failed every time. Restarting Postman and python did not help. Is it because postman has bandwidth issue? Thanks for any comments.

This is how I connected the nodes. Again it works for the other two scripts.

```
@app.route('/connect_node', methods = ['POST'])
def connect_node():
    json = request.get_json()
    nodes = json.get('nodes')
    if nodes is None:
        return "No node", 400
    for node in nodes:
        blockchain.add_node(node)
    response = {'message': 'All the nodes are now connected. The Mycoin     Blockchain now contains the following nodes:',
                'total_nodes': list(blockchain.nodes)}
    return jsonify(response), 201
```

When I try the debug mode, this is the log:

```
  File "D:\Dropbox\3350\homework\mini blockchain and crypto currency\MyCoin 
cryptocurrency\node2.py", line 161, in connect_node
    nodes = json.get('nodes')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

A more detailed debug log here:

[image]

Comment: Do you have logs from `5001` server? Try running it with Debug flag. Did it successfully binded to that port? Maybe it's taken by some other app.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AdrianKrupa. I am quite new to Postman. May I ask how I can check and release this port? I did not find logs of the server on Postman.

Comment: Check the logs from flask app. Run flask with `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001, Debug=True)` and check the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It traced back to this line: nodes = json.get('nodes') in python and said AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Answer (score 1):

Set `JSON` in Body.

[image: bbb]

[image: bbb]

It also sets `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.